# New Activity issuing nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android

I am trying to start a new activity to display a list of results from a search. I have been through the android dev stuff and androidhive and through similar posts here dealing with populating a listview with an arraylist in a new activity and I just cant seem to get this to work. I would really appreciate any help, been battling with this for a few days now.

Here are the relevants parts of my main activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultsActivity.class);
ArrayList<String> myCommonFilms = new ArrayList<String>(commonFilms.getCommonFilms(titleOne, titleTwo));
Log.d("myCommonFilms", myCommonFilms.toString());
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("myCommonFilmsList", myCommonFilms);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the new activity:

```
public class DisplayResultsActivity extends Activity {
private ListView listView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_results);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> myCommonFilms = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("myCommonFilms");
        Log.d("myCommonFilms in display", myCommonFilms.toString());
        Log.d("ArrayListContents", myCommonFilms.toString());
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.expandable_list_content, myCommonFilms);
        Log.d("ArrayAdapterContents", arrayAdapter.toString());
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_results, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest in case something is up there:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tot.tipofthetongue"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_results" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my main activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_screen_bg" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_screen_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findMovies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/buttonText"
        android:onClick="displayResults" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and lastly the layout of my new activity for displaying the results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/results_bg"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >

</ListView>
```

and here is the error log:
    09-13 22:42:00.127: W/dalvikvm(1168): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tot.tipofthetongue/com.tot.tipofthetongue.DisplayResultsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.tot.tipofthetongue.DisplayResultsActivity.onCreate(DisplayResultsActivity.java:30)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-13 22:42:00.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     ... 11 more

Comment: please share the logs with the exception, that might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is due to the naming / referencing of your ListView.

Either use this as the ListView id :

```xml
android:id="@+id/myList"
```

And reference it this way in the onCreate method :

```java
listView = (ListView) findViewById ( R.id.myList );
```

---

**Or** you can make your new activity extend **ListActivity** instead of **Activity**

```
public class DisplayResultsActivity extends ListActivity
```

And in this case you MUST name your **ListView** as follows :

```xml
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

And you will be able to reference it in your activity as you already did :

```java
listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Or you can also you the following method :

```
listView = getListView ();
```

---

### EDIT

---

I think I know why you are getting a null pointer exception, here's why :

You are adding to the intent a list under the key : **myCommonFilmsList** "

```java
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("myCommonFilmsList", myCommonFilms);
```

However you are trying to retrieve the list using another key : **myCommonFilms**

```
ArrayList<String> myCommonFilms = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("myCommonFilms");
```

This is definitely why you are getting a null pointer exception. A good practice to avoid such issues is to have a static attributes for such keys, and hence you will not have to remember all the keys.

Personally, I would have done the following :

Add the following attribute to your new activity class :

```
public static final String COMMON_FILMS = DisplayResultsActivity.class.getName () + ".COMMON_FILMS";
```

In this manner, you add the list to the intent as follows :

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra( DisplayResultsActivity.COMMON_FILMS , myCommonFilms);
```

And you retrieve it from the intent in your new activity as follows :

```
ArrayList<String> myCommonFilms = intent.getStringArrayListExtra ( DisplayResultsActivity.COMMON_FILMS );
```

**OR** you can simply change one of two keys : **myCommonFilmsList** or **myCommonFilms**, because they must be the same (on adding to and retrieving from the intent).

Let me know if this is the issue.

Comment: when i do it the first way I get your content must have listview whos id attribute is android.R.id.list. I was getting that error before and then I got rid of it but I got the nullpointer. When I do it the second way I still get the same nullpointer error. Same thing when I do:  ArrayList<String> myCommonFilms = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("myCommonFilms");

Comment: Please see my additional solution under 'EDIT' , I believe now I know why you are getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: You were right! what you suggested in the edit, that did it thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_results" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: this issues a warning: exported activity does not require permission. not sure what that means. and it returns the same error. I updated the original post to include logcat.